# .NET Core 2 Facebook Access Token

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, .net-core-2.0

I'd like to get access token  from facebook in C#.
I've no found any code that perform this action in Core 2.
I'm using .Net Core 2 MVC.
In my startup.cs I'm using this:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddFacebook((o) =>
            {
                o.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
                o.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
                o.SaveTokens = true;
                o.Scope.Add("email");
                o.Scope.Add("user_birthday");
                o.Scope.Add("user_gender");
                o.Scope.Add("user_posts");
                o.Scope.Add("manage_pages");
                o.Scope.Add("publish_pages");
            });
```

In my controller I try to get the token, but I've got "null" back.

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
        {  
            var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

            return Json(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("access_token", accessToken));
        }
```

Is there any elegant way to get the Access Token?

Answer (score 0):

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
 {
     options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

  })
 .AddJwtBearer(options =>
 {
     options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;

 })
 .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
 {
     facebookOptions.AppId = "";
     facebookOptions.AppSecret = "";
     facebookOptions.SaveTokens = true;
     facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
     facebookOptions.Scope.Add("user_birthday");
     facebookOptions.Scope.Add("user_gender");
     facebookOptions.Scope.Add("user_posts");
     facebookOptions.Scope.Add("manage_pages");
     facebookOptions.Scope.Add("publish_pages");
 })
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

**Controller**

```
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
result.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token");
```